# React app that uses hooks and shows a random image every two seconds

Tags: random, image, react.js, jsx

React beginner here. I'm practicing state and hooks, and I wanted to create a small app that every two seconds fetches an image URL from a service (that returns random images) and shows the returned image.

The idea is to make it simple and readable. Do you have any suggestions?

```javascript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = imageUrl ? 2000 : 0;

    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay)).then(() => {
      fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setImageUrl(data.message))
        .catch(err => console.log("Problemino!", err))
    });
  }, [imageUrl]);

  return(
    <div>
      <img src={imageUrl} alt="Random doggo!" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

With readability in mind: I'd avoid the unnecessary promise wrapper and promise chaining, and take the async/await approach instead. It flattens the code and I find it easier to follow.

Your `useEffect` would look something like this after refactoring:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const delay = imageUrl ? 2000 : 0;

  setTimeout(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
      const data = await res.json();
      setImageUrl(data.message);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Problemino!", e);
    }
  }, delay);
}, [imageUrl]);
```

One thing to note: if there's an error, `setImageUrl` won't be called, and so the image will stop updating. This is because the `imageUrl` dependency for `useEffect` won't have changed. This is true in your original code too. I'd recommend better error handling to ensure that it keeps retrying.

P.s. I thoroughly enjoyed viewing dog pictures whilst looking into this :D